# Finding Element That Doesn't Have a Hidden Parent?

Tags: css

I have a few elements that match a selector and have parents which are toggled between display:none and no style. I'd like to select the first visible one using a CSS selector.

Ex: in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v2nah9sd/2/) I'd like my selector in the JS portion to pick div C rather than div A.

```
const found = document.querySelector(".find-me"); // .find-me:has(not(display=none)?
console.log(found.innerText);
```

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: I suspect there isn't an answer using pure CSS selectors for all the situations you might want as you can't test CSS property values that way but for the simple case you give this will work on many of the popular browsers nowadays: :not(.hiding) > .find-me